# Why is ValidateChildren always returning true?

Tags: winforms, validation, errorprovider

I have a WinForms dialog where my control is being validated and is calling `ErrorProvider`'s `SetError` in its validation method, but the `ValidateChildren` method of my form is still always returning true. Why?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `Cancel` attribute of the `CancelEventArgs` object being passed to your validation method:

```
    private void SinglePromptField_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.errorProvider.SetError(this.control, "Invalid value!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```